# sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1 returns not found on 18.04

Tags: boot

I recently upgraded to 18.04 on a single boot machine. I got the grup menu one morning, used advanced options and got the requires a manual fsck. I typed sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1 (I also tried the command without the space after the -f) and got the response sh: sudo: not found. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: How many partitions do have on this system as I think the command should have been `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2`

Comment: run `lsblk -f` and lets see how partitions there are!

Comment: Turns out it was using sudo in the command line. When I typed just fsck -fy /dev/sda1 everything went as it should and I'm back up. You all are the greatest. Thank you.

Comment: In recovery your are root. No need to start commands with sudo

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is sudo? Maybe it is not installed?

> apt-get install sudo

Then try to update.